# What to do with left over rejuvelac grains

Tags: grains

I have been making rejuvelac from wheat berries in order to make vegan cheese. After I am through with the rejuvelac, I have been throwing away the wheat berries. I tried to find something else I could do with them. The only things I saw were to grow wheat grass or dehydrate them.

I don't wish to grow wheat grass and do not have a dehydrator.

Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Generally, "what can I do with _____" questions are off topic here, though we do sometimes make exceptions for very unusual ingredients. I think this may fall into that exception but I want to warn you that the community may close this question.

Comment: You could incorporate them into a sprouted grain bread?

Comment: A quick Google search came up with several ideas, one of which is making bread as @SourDoh mentions in his comment. Others include making crackers or drying until crunchy and using as a salad topping.

Answer (score 3):

I love croutons in my salad, but I don't want to use refined flour products. I mix sprouted grains with a cashew cream blend, add some miso, kimchi, veggie mix left from my juicer, nutritional yeast flakes and herbs, mix it all together and dehydrate at under 104 degrees for a day, flip it over to dh another day and then crumble it up in a zip lock bag with a food grade desiccant packet.  The chunks make awesome croutons!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just seen this. It says you can use your Rejuvelac sprouts to make the bread 
http://www.living-foods.com/recipes/wigmore.html

Answer (score -3):

Discard or compost them in a legal manner

Comment: Unfortunately, your post does not answer the question. The OP specifically states that he wants to use the leftover grains rather than throw them away.

Comment: Composting the spent ingredient is a perfectly legitimate use that does not just put then down the garbage disposal or send them to fill up the landfill.

Comment: I dunno, I see where you're coming from, but I think this is mostly just saying what the best way to *not* use them is, rather than how to use them in the kitchen. We get a fair number of questions like this, and I don't know that we need "compost them" as an answer on every one.

Comment: There are many questions here that are going to receive answers the questioner dos not want to hear or listen to. It is the nature of the problem they are asking to resolveThere is no 'good' use for something that is essentially garbage.
OK, put them in a bowl, add 'vegan' milk and a sweentener that is acceptavble to your lifestyle/diet then eat them. They might taste very good.